# chart libraries that work on IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, charts

I'm looking for (javascript or HTML-based) chart libraries that work on Internet Explorer. Any suggestions? Interactivity is a plus, but not necessary.

I've tried using Flot, but I'm having trouble getting it to work in IE8 (though a recent patch fixed it for IE9). I've also used the Google Chart API, but something a little more easily customizable would be preferred.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends a bit on what all you need to accomplish with your library, 
but maybe you'll find these musings useful...

You can do quite a bit with just **CSS**
and make your own "library", albeit a limited one, 
for graphs such as horizontal bar charts. 
For instance:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/bargraph/demo.html

http://applestooranges.com/blog/post/css-for-bar-graphs/

**jQuery Sparklines** is not a true "library", either, 
but it has some great options, and it works all the way 
back to IE 6. Definitely underrated.

http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/

**Highcharts** could be a good bet.

http://www.highcharts.com/

If **Protovis** had full support for IE, it might have to be 
considered the best, because it adheres to best practices for data visualization. 
However, it doesn't have the world's most accessible api, and it doesn't support IE, at least not entirely - read issue 15:

http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/

http://code.google.com/p/protovis-js/issues/detail?id=15

**Amcharts** has flash-based charts at the moment, but take note: 
I believe they are working on javascript library for their charts.
If and when they do come out with their library, I have a feeling 
it will be pretty good.

http://www.amcharts.com/

Please also consider this when choosing a library:
if you see a plethora of 3-d stacked pie charts, or glossy bars, or drop-shadows, 
then be careful: it's a good bet the makers of those charts didn't create them with 
data visualization best practices in mind.

Comment: +1 I'd vote this up more if I could. Wish I'd known about half these libraries before writing my own!!

Comment: jQuery sparklines looks very cool indeed, I'll try it out! [I also considered Highcharts previously, but didn't want to deal with licensing issues :(.]

Answer (score 7):

For any JavaScript chart library to work on IE 6,7,8, they need to render the chart in VML. Hence, libraries rendering using SVG or Canvas only wouldn't work (hence d3.js based solutions wouldn't work). The following libraries currently have support on IE 6,7,8 as they use a hybrid of SVG and VML:

FusionCharts JavaScript Charting @ http://www.fusioncharts.com

HighCharts @ http://www.highcharts.com

Any JavaScript charting library built on top of Raphael JS e.g., amcharts, gRaphael would also work on IE6,7,8.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried telerik

http://www.telerik.com/

i did not use it myself, but a friend of mine thinks it is doing the job.

Comment: That's a CMS now, not a chart javascript library.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the recently released [amCharts JavaScript](http://www.amcharts.com/javascript/) bundle. It brings all the interactivity of the Flash charts but in JS/HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/index.php) in the past and it worked well for me. It's a jQuery plugin though; not sure if that matters to you or not.