# Javascript charting library for IE9

Tags: javascript, charts, internet-explorer-9

I want to create a reporting dashboard. However, I only have available IE9 to show it. So using the ultra cool libs like d3, highcharts and also chartsjs, do not really work well.

Any recommendations for a javascript charting library to create my dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChartJs works for IE8+. It is mentioned in the documentation : http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

Also check this question: [chart libraries that work on IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475923/chart-libraries-that-work-on-ie)